Exercise on Schwarz inequality: $\left(\int_a^b |f(x)| dx \right)^2 \leq (b-a)\int_a^b|f(x)|^2 dx$
I'm trying this exercise:
Suppose that $f(x)$ is a complex-valued function square integrable on the interval $]a,b[$. Show that
$$\left(\int_a^b |f(x)| dx \right)^2 \leq (b-a)\int_a^b|f(x)|^2 dx$$
I've tried using Schwarz inequality starting from the RHS
$$(b-a)\int_a^b|f(x)|^2 dx = \|1\|^2\|f\|^2\geq |\langle f,1\rangle|^2=\left|\int_a^bf(x)dx\right|^2$$
but now I have no idea on how to go on considering that in general $\left|\int_a^bf(x)dx\right|\leq \int_a^b |f(x)| dx$. Can you please help me?

Your inequality is equally applicable to $|f|$ in place of $f$.

Let $\langle f, g \rangle = \int_a^b f(x) \overline{g(x)}\, dx$ and apply the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality on $\langle |f|, 1 \rangle,$ where $1$ is the constant function with value $1.$
